# XSLT 2.0: How to replace() part of an element's value and use the result in a select operation?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I've done a bit of XPath in C++ and C# applications, but this is my first time really using it directly in XSLT.  I have an XML file that is formatted like this:

```
<topLevel>
  <foo>
    <bar>prefix1_Taxi</bar>
    ...
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>prefix1_SchoolBus</bar>
    ...
  </foo>
  ...
  <foo>
    <bar>prefix2_Taxi</bar>
    ...
  </foo>
  <foo>
    <bar>prefix2_SchoolBus</bar>
    ...
  </foo>
</topLevel>
```

First, I want to select only the `<foo>` elements that have a `<bar>` element that starts with "prefix1_."  This appears to work:

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo[bar[starts-with(., 'prefix1_')]]">

   <!-- Style and format the values from child elements of the "prefix1_" <foo> -->

</xsl:for-each>
```

From inside the `for-each` block, I then want to select the `<foo>` element that contains the corresponding "prefix2_" element.  I then want to pull data out of each as I see fit.

For example, when the `for-each` has selected "prefix1_Taxi", I want to then select the `foo` element that contains the "prefix2_Taxi" `bar` element.

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo[bar[starts-with(., 'prefix1_')]]">

   <!-- Retrieve the corresponding "prefix2_" foo -->
   <!-- Style and format the values from child elements of the "prefix1_" <foo> -->
   <!-- Style and format the values from child elements of the "prefix2_" <foo> -->

</xsl:for-each>
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about this.  In a traditional program I would do something like the following pseudocode:

```
String buf = barElement.Name.Replace("prefix1_", String.Empty);
XmlNode otherFoo = document.SelectSingleNode("foo[bar[" + buf + "]]");
```

However XSLT obviously works with a different paradigm for retrieving values and manipulating data, so I'm trying to break out of my old mode of thinking.

Using what I've gathered from some googling on XSLT, I came up with something pretty ugly:

1. Select the foo element containing a bar that starts with some text:

   `foo[bar[starts-with(., ...)`
2. Replace the "prefix1_" in our current `<bar>` element:

   `replace(<xsl:value-of select='bar'/>, 'prefix1_', '')`

This yields a pretty ugly mess:

```
<xsl:value-of select="foo[bar[starts-with(., replace(<xsl:value-of select='bar'/>, 'prefix1_', ''))]]" />
```

I'm also pretty sure that the `<xsl:value-of>` element isn't correct.

How do I go about this?  I suspect that I'm missing some core concepts of how to express this concept in XSLT.  I'm slogging through the [w3.org page](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) on XSLT but I still need *much* more study and practice.

Comment: You don't need to call back from XPath into XSLT: the xsl:value-of is unnecessary and wrong. `replace(current()/bar, 'prefix1_', '')` would work fine. But @Ben has given you a more complete solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XSL stylesheet should give you some flexibility about what you do with the `foo` elements that contain "prefix2".

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Matches the top level element and selects the children with prefix1 text. -->
  <xsl:template match="topLevel">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="foo[bar[starts-with(., 'prefix1_')]]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- We're at a foo element with prefix1 text. Select the siblings of the 
       same vehicle type, with prefix2 text. -->
  <xsl:template match="foo[bar[starts-with(., 'prefix1_')]]">
    <xsl:variable name="vehicle" select="substring-after(bar, 'prefix1_')"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="../foo[bar = concat('prefix2_', $vehicle)]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- In this template, you can do whatever you want with the foo element containing
       the prefix2 vehicles. This example just copies the element and its children. -->
  <xsl:template match="foo[bar[starts-with(., 'prefix2_')]]">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each select="foo[bar[starts-with(., 'prefix1_')]]">
    <xsl:variable name="new-text" as=xs:string" select="replace(bar/text(), '1', '2')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(../foo/bar[$new-text]/text(), ' OR DO SOMETHING MORE USEFUL THAN APPENDING TEXT')" />  
</xsl:for-each>
```

You are on the `foo` element containing the "prefix1" text within the loop, and then change to the other bar element's text and operate on it, whatever you want to do.

Remark: You might need to add `xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` to your XSLT root element for the `xs:string`in my sample to work. And probably it would also work without the intermediate variable, but I think it makes the code slightly more readable.